# CSS flexcontainer not high enough after flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

This footer has a flexcontainer (id="footerline") whose flex-wrap property is set to wrap. The container contains two divs (class="footerbutton"). When wrapping takes place on small screens, the second container moves to a new line, but the container's height does not adjust, so the two lines overlap. I could fix this by removing the padding of the buttons in the two divs, but this is clearly not what I would like to do.

So what can I do to make sure the flexcontainer has just the right height after wrapping (and before wrapping, too, of course, but that is not the problem)? Setting the height of the container to something like 100px is not an option as I wish the container to be just high enough to contain the content, be it wrapped or not.

I have studied numerous other questions about similar situations and their answers, but all my experiments that resulted from this did not help in my case.

Thank you.

Malte

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
             #footerline {display:flex; justify-content: space-around; flex-wrap: wrap;
               padding: 20px; width: 100%; background: #132a40}
            .footerbutton a {color:whitesmoke; padding: 20px; margin-left:10px; 
               text-decoration: none; background-color: green}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <footer>
            <div id="footerline">
                <div class="footerbutton">
                    <a href="Imprint.html">Imprint -- Cookies -- Privacy</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <nav class="footerbutton">
                        <a href="english.html">English</a>
                        <a href="swedish.html">Swedish</a>
                        <a href="german.html">German</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use footer bottom in css for Footerbutton

if you dont  needed in Webview just add it in Media query.

```
.footerbutton a {
color: whitesmoke;
padding: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: green;
margin bottom: 50px;
}
```

if not needed in WebView place that Marginbottom in media query

Answer (score 0):

Check there are full code `display: flex` issues here. if you want space in a mobile device `add media query` for mobile.

```css
#footerline {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background: #132a40;
}
.footerbutton{
  display:flex;
}
.footerbutton a {
  color:whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left:10px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: green;
  
}
#footerline > div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
        <footer>
            <div id="footerline">
                <div class="footerbutton">
                    <a href="Imprint.html">Imprint -- Cookies -- Privacy</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <nav class="footerbutton">
                        <a href="english.html">English</a>
                        <a href="swedish.html">Swedish</a>
                        <a href="german.html">German</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked after your code. From what I understood your approach to flex is not working right.I would suggest to add a property min-height say `min-height:200px` to your main footerline div. Also the flex is wrapping only the two div elements inside footer. You need to need `display:flex` and `flex-wrap:wrap` to both the div elements inside your footerline div. Try this solution I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it is working for you

```
#footerline > div {
   display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It did not solve my issue, though.

Comment: Hy @Malte please check i have add full code with CSS